# How do I fix my looping for this Single Player Dice Game (4 - 4 sided die)? Issues with Scanner input not yielding correct outputs

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

// I've been working on this all day but still seem to be stuck.
// I'm not getting any obvious errors but the looping seems to be broken.
// I'm a beginner so its very likely I missed something big but just overlooked it.
// This assignment is due at midnight for my class lol.
// I feel like I constructed the base format decently however my unfamiliarity with using loops is really throwing me for one. I've looked online elsewhere but many of the "dice" programs people have made only pertain to one 6-sided die and do not involve a turn based user input.
// Any useful tips would be fantastic, is there a more efficient way to go about constructing this game? I know creating multiple classes would have cleaned up the look of the program but I'm really only looking for functionality at the moment.

```
package prgm06;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGame 
{   
    public static void main(String []args) //main DiceGame loop.
    {
        String answer;
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userWin = 0, userLose = 0, turnCounter = 0;
        System.out.println("\t" + "Welcome to Computer Dice");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("The outcome of your roll will determine" + "\n" + "if you win or lose the round." + "\n");
        System.out.println("Any Quad and you win.");
        System.out.println("Any Triple and you win.");
        System.out.println("Any High Pair and you win.");
        System.out.println("Anything else and you lose.");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to play? [y,n]: ");
        do { // I always want the dice to roll unless "n" is selected.
            answer = stdIn.next();
            int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        }
        while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); // issues with "y" not printing if/ else statements
        {
            int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            System.out.println(d1 + "\t" + d2 + "\t" + d3 + "\t" + d4);
            if ((d1 == d2) && (d1 == d3) && (d1 == d4))
            {
                userWin++;
                System.out.println("\n" + "Round Results: Win");
                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
            }
            else
            {
                userLose++;
                System.out.println("\n" + "Round Results: Loss");
                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
            }
        }
//      do
        {
            answer = stdIn.next();  // I'm not sure if i need to keep using this at each segment
        }
        for(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n");;  // will not print on first user input of "n".
        {
//          System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Game Results:");
            System.out.println("User won: " + userWin + " Games.");
            System.out.println("User lost: " + userLose + " Games.");

            if (userWin > userLose)
            {
                System.out.println("Your win/loss ratio is: " + (userWin/userLose) + " Good Job!");
                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
            }
            else if (userWin < userLose)
            {
                System.out.println("Your win/loss ratio is: " + (userWin/userLose) + " You shouldn't bet money on this game...");
                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Your win/loss ratio is: 1.0 .");
                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
            }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your code.  Some errors were related to syntax, and some were possibly related to the logical flows.  This should work as a base, and you can modify and improve it as you see fit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGame {
    public static void main(String []args) //main DiceGame loop.
    {
        String answer;
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userWin = 0, userLose = 0, turnCounter = 0;
        System.out.println("\t" + "Welcome to Computer Dice");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("The outcome of your roll will determine" + "\n" + "if you win or lose the round." + "\n");
        System.out.println("Any Quad and you win.");
        System.out.println("Any Triple and you win.");
        System.out.println("Any High Pair and you win.");
        System.out.println("Anything else and you lose.");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        do { // I always want the dice to roll unless "n" is selected.

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Do you wish to play? [y,n]: ");
            answer = stdIn.next();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

                turnCounter++;

                int d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
                int d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
                int d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
                int d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;

                System.out.println(d1 + "\t" + d2 + "\t" + d3 + "\t" + d4);

                if ((d1 == d2) || (d1 == d3) || (d1 == d4) || (d2 == d3) || (d2 == d4) || (d3 == d4) {
                    userWin++;
                    System.out.println("\n" + "Round Results: Win");
                    System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
                } else {
                    userLose++;
                    System.out.println("\n" + "Round Results: Loss");
                    System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");
                }

                System.out.println("Game Results:");
                System.out.println("User won: " + userWin + " Games.");
                System.out.println("User lost: " + userLose + " Games.");

                System.out.println("Your win/loss ratio is: " + userWin + ":" + userLose);

                if (userWin > userLose) {System.out.println("Good Job!");}

                if (userWin < userLose) {System.out.println("You shouldn't bet money on this game...");}

                System.out.println(turnCounter + " Rounds played.");

            }

        } while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

Some points to note:

- The game will keep running as long as the user types in 'y', since that is your condition: answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y").
- I changed the win condition logic to check for at least a pair using the logical OR operator
- I removed the division operator for the ratio result for win/loss and just replaced it with a display of wins:losses; This could be changed if you want it to calculate for an actual percentage or decimal value, but you have to check for cases where losses == 0 to prevent a divide by zero error
- The Do-While loop should encompass all of the gameplay from start to finish, so the question that asks you to play again should go at the start or at the end of this loop (I placed it at the start)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it :D  Just comment here if there's anything in the code you want explained.